# Compare 7-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have to compare two 7-dimensional Arrays and for every match i have to count +1 to a new array.

This is the array with user-input, which i want to compare with the "right values"

```
Array([task] => Array(
                [OF] => Array(
                                [nr] => Array(
                                                [1] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [0] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => :
                                                                                        )
                                                                            )
                                                            )
                                                [2] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [0] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => +
                                                                                        )
                                                                            )
                                                            )
                                                [3] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [1] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => -
                                                                                        )
                                                                            [2] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => +
                                                                                        )
                                                                            )
                                                            )
                                                [4] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [0] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => -
                                                                                    )
                                                                        )
                                                            )
                                                [5] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [0] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => *
                                                                                        )
                                                                            )
                                                            )
                                                [6] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [0] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => :
                                                                                        )
                                                                            )
                                                            )
                                                [7] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [0] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => *
                                                                                        )
                                                                            )
                                                            )
                                            )
                            )
                ),
                [TA] => Array(
                                [nr] => Array(
                                                [1] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [0] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => :
                                                                                        )
                                                                            )
                                                            )
                                                [2] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [0] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => +
                                                                                        )
                                                                            )
                                                            )
                                                [3] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [1] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => -
                                                                                        )
                                                                            [2] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => +
                                                                                        )
                                                                            )
                                                            )
                                                [4] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [0] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => -
                                                                                    )
                                                                        )
                                                            )
                                                [5] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [0] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => *
                                                                                        )
                                                                            )
                                                            )
                                                [6] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [0] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => :
                                                                                        )
                                                                            )
                                                            )
                                                [7] => Array(
                                                            [pos] => Array(
                                                                            [0] => Array(
                                                                                        [value] => *
                                                                                        )
                                                                            )
                                                            )
                                            )
                            )
)
```

The right values are in the same structure with different values.

Now i have to loop through the arrays and check if the user-input is == the "right value".

Sorry if it's hard to understand. It's slightly hard to explain.

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you all in advance.

EDIT:// i want to know the amount of right values of the 'task' arrays e.g. OF => 12 , TA => 3

Comment: `array_unique( array_merge($array1, $array2) );`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well, what you need is a recursive comparision. Here is my adhoc code, I didn't test it:

```
function compareArrays($array1, $array2) {
  $retval = 0;

  for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {

    // The values are arrays, we need a recursive comparation again
    if (is_array($array1[$i]) && is_array($array2[$i])) {
      $retval += compareArrays($array1[$i], $array2[$i]);

    // The values are equal, we can increase the counter
    } else if ($array1[$i] === $array2[$i]) {
      $retval++;

    // The values are different
    } else {
      // Is there anything to do?
    }

  }

  return $retval;
}
```